# Não consigo editar a data set do charts.js usando javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu estava a tentar editar a data set do meu grafico com javascript mas estou obtendo este erro:

```
index.html:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'labels' of undefined
    at mainmain (index.html:26)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

O meu codigo js:

```
  function mainmain(data) {

    oug.data.labels.push("new");
    oug.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
      dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    oug.update();

  }
```

Meu HTML:

```
  <canvas id="oug" width="378" height="94" class="sparkline"
    data-chart="spark-line"
    data-dataset="[[10, 20, 30, 40, 30, 10, 30, 10]]"
    data-dataset-options="[{borderColor: '#1ca8dd', backgroundColor:'rgba(28,168,221,.03)'}]"
    data-labels="['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']"
    style="width: 189px; height: 47px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Seu código está incompleto, onde chama a função **mainmain()**?

Comment: @LeAndrade chamo pelo terminal